# Application wide background color for LinearLayout with Material design

Tags: android, material-design

I have a layout in my android application that looks as shown below, nothing fancy, just three buttons placed horizontally. But when using Material design style the default background color for this LinearLayout is black.

Is there a way to control background colors of all Linerar layout when using Material Theme? I looked through themes_matrial.xml there isn't section where I saw that sets up universal background color. Do I need to manually set it in my xml file for all LinearLayouts?

My styles.xml looks like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

My LinearLayout is as follows:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mostfav"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="mostFav"
            android:text="Most Fav" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sortDateButton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="sortByDate"
            android:text="@string/sortdate" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sortTextButton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="sortByText"
            android:text="@string/sorttext" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tweetCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't do it by using `style.xml` but you can do it by creating custom LinearLayout.

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    public MyLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

In your xml file,

```
<com.yourpackage.name.MyLinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></com.yourpackage.name.MyLinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps :)